# Civivolunteer won't show link unless logged in as admin

Tags: civivolunteer

We are using Civi 4.7.22 on Wordpress 4.8.22.  We recently installed the updated version of civivolunteer 4.7.21-2.2.2

After setting up civivolunteer and adding it to an event, the volunteer link does not show up for anyone who is signing up for the event unless they are logged onto Wordpress as an Administrator role.  Even being logged in as a Subscriber will not show the Volunteer opportunities link, even when I copy and paste the actual link.

Am I missing something or is this a known issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved,
Be sure to set permissions in Administer > Users and Permissions. 
Check all roles you want to access volunteer opportunities at CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer and CiviCRM: access AJAX API